# inline style causing error

Tags: html, css

Why would this inline style be causing an error? I'm using intelij as my IDA and it's saying invalid value for `style="background-image:url(../images/email-bg.jpg);"`

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="489" width="639" align="left" style="background-image:url(../images/email-bg.jpg);">
```

The reason I'm using inline styling is because I'm doing an HTML e-mailer.

Comment: Why are you using a path when the code will be in an email? Unless I've missed something, I didn't think there was a directory structure for the image to live in

Comment: When you send this email out to people, where will `../images/email-bg.jpg` point to? You'll need to use an absolute path `http://yoursite.com/images/email-bg.jpg`

Comment: Yea I totally forgot yes I need to use an absolute path. thanks

Comment: @Sachleen, you should submit that as an answer, as your response is more meaningful than mine - and it would be wrong for me to try and take the credit

Answer (score 6):

When you send this email out to people, where will `../images/email-bg.jpg` point to?

You'll need to use an absolute path. Something like `http://yoursite.com/images/email-bg.jpg` so it will point to your image no matter where you're looking at it from.